# How to check if a Google Sheets cell has multiple lines

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-forms

Using a [Google Form](https://docs.google.com/forms/d/e/1FAIpQLScsA5w7W_9MoaDMgfl5e5yjdZNEu4DU2Ho6D4jj-SlajSQbzg/) to get information for a [Google Sheet](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1joH3YgX4pZpOSS6yV6pRPf0cve60kF9KdyHMvO1fTXE), a few questions sometimes have multiline responses. Want to check if the data in cells E|F|I have more than 4 lines and autoResize height, if not keep rowHeight at 67. Every time new data is submitted, it autoResizes, which is not desired for data with less than 4 lines of data. Why is it not keeping set height?

Maybe this can be fixed by looking at each row on form submit, if it's greater than 4 lines autoResize else set rowHeight to 67. Not sure what the syntax for this would be. Maybe have to check if data has more than or less than 4 return characters and format according?

Currently use this code in the Form App Script to sort newest data to the top and format accordingly

```
function onFormSubmit(e)
{
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.openById('1joH3YgX4pZpOSS6yV6pRPf0cve60kF9KdyHMvO1fTXE');
  var sheet = ss.getSheetByName("Form Responses 1");
  var range = sheet.getRange("A2:P");
  var row = sheet.getRange(2, 1, 1, sheet.getMaxColumns());
  var cell = sheet.getRange("J2");

  range.sort([{column: 2, ascending: false}]);
 
  sheet.setRowHeight(2, 67);

  row
     .setFontFamily("Arial")
     .setFontWeight("bold")
     .setFontSize(10)
     .setHorizontalAlignment("center")
     .setVerticalAlignment("middle");

  if(!cell.isBlank())
  {
    row
       .setFontColor('#FF0000')
       .setFontSize(12);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I tried checking the spreadsheet with the sample data but it seems you haven’t shared it, so I elaborated an answer with a general approach to your issue. *Please make sure to modify the columns or rows that fit your data, take this as a refence.*

These are the changes I made:

```js
for(var i = 0; i<5; i++)  
  {
    var val = ss.getSheetByName("Form Responses 1").getRange(2, 1+i).getValue(); 
     
    if(val.length > 50) //test different values that work for the data you are entering. 
    {  
      
      range.setWrapStrategy(SpreadsheetApp.WrapStrategy.WRAP)
    }
    else 
   { 
      ss.getSheetByName("Form Responses 1").setRowHeightsForced(1,1,67)
   }
```

With your current code, adding the changes I made will look like this:

```js
function onFormSubmit()
{
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.openById('1joH3YgX4pZpOSS6yV6pRPf0cve60kF9KdyHMvO1fTXE');
  var sheet = ss.getSheetByName("Form Responses 1");
  var range = sheet.getRange("A2:P");
  var row = sheet.getRange(2, 1, 1, sheet.getMaxColumns());
  var cell = sheet.getRange("J2");

  range.sort([{column: 2, ascending: false}]);
 
  sheet.setRowHeight(2, 67);

  row
     .setFontFamily("Arial")
     .setFontWeight("bold")
     .setFontSize(10)
     .setHorizontalAlignment("center")
     .setVerticalAlignment("middle");
  
  if(!cell.isBlank())
  {
    row
       .setFontColor('#FF0000')
       .setFontSize(12);
  }
    for(var i = 0; i<5; i++) 
  {
    var val = sheet.getRange(2, 1+i).getValue();
         
    if(val.length > 50)  //test different values that work for the data you are entering
    {  
      
      range.setWrapStrategy(SpreadsheetApp.WrapStrategy.WRAP)
    }
    else 
   { 
      sheet.setRowHeightsForced(1,1,67)
   } 
  }  
}
```

I hope this addresses what you were trying to achieve, feel free to check the references below, if any questions let me know :)

#### References:

- [setRowHeightsForced()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/sheet#setrowheightsforcedstartrow,-numrows,-height)
- [setWrapStrategy(strategy)](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#setwrapstrategystrategy)
- [Options for the WrapStrategy](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/wrap-strategy)

---